# Autocomplete character highlighting

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I've made a search bar using v-select, autocomplete and a custom filter function using vuetify. While it is filtering how I want, the characters that v-select is 'highlighting' (Changes font color) as I type into the search bar isn't behaving how I want. Basically, it will highlight it according to the default filtering function (Which is highlighting a matching substring), else it will highlight the entire entry instead of the part that is being matched according to my filtering function. Is there a way to also edit the highlighting of autocomplete?

Template:

```
  <v-select
    :items="owners"
    v-model="test_owners"
    label="Test Owner"
    hide-details
    return-object
    multiple
    autocomplete
    :filter = "filter_owners"
    :disabled="!enableOwners"
  ></v-select>
```

Filter method

```
  methods: {
    filter_owners(item, querytext, itemText) {
      if (querytext) {
        var regex = new RegExp('.*' + querytext.split('').join('.*') + '.*');
        return regex.test(itemText.toLowerCase())
      }
      return true
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you post your source code 。If not we dont know how you are doing and which part need to fix

Comment: @DavidJapan sorry, just added it

Comment: I am interested in this as well, how to modify highlighted text?